# relative position DIV shrinks with absolute position images inside

Tags: html, css, marquee

I'm making a replacement for `<marquee>`. I have a `<div>` with `<image>`s inside. In order to move the `<image>`s I need them to be `position:absolute`, and the `<div>` must have `overflow:hidden` to hide the "excess" on the sides, here is the code :

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative">
  <img src="photo.jpg" style="position:absolute" name="img" />
  ... (many more images)
</div>
```

The javascript part is just a timer decreasing the `left` attribute of the `<image>`s.

The problem is that the `<div>` shrinks and disappears when the `<image>`s are `position:absolute` and this happens because of the `overflow:hidden`. I tried using an outer `<div>` but the same happened. I cannot set a fixed `height` to the `<div>` because the user can upload any size of images, big or small, and in any number.

¿How to keep the `<image>`s absolute and hide the "excess" outside the `<div>` without shrinking?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your approach will work, but this should answer your question. Just add a "hidden" image, which has no position absolute:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative">
  <img src="photo.jpg" style="visibility:hidden" name="img" />
  <img src="photo.jpg" style="position:absolute" name="img" />
  ... (many more images)
</div>
```

With visibility:hidden the element will not be visible, but the space will be used. You can probably remove that, since the other images will overlap.

I hope it helps.